# Log and Record Externally loaded SWF in FLASH AS3

Tags: flash, apache-flex, swfloader

I have loaded an external SWF in my flash application and showing it in a space. As the external SWF is a sub-part of my main flash application, I would like to know a way to record , trace or log all the http request and responses made by it, is there anyway of accomplishing this feat?

Comment: Could TraceTarget work? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/logging/targets/TraceTarget.html

Answer (score 0):

Its best to use MonsterDebugger for this. -> [MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/)

Edit: Sorry I misunderstood, i thought this is for debugging.

You can make your own events for this, listen to them from your Main swf and dispatch them from the chid swf.
EDIT2: This Link explains it very well. Make event types for your needs and dispatch them in the child swf [Creating and dispatching Custom Events](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_AS3__Creating_and_dispatching_Custom_Events-17609.html)

Comment: thanks for your feedback but I don't want to use it for debugging.. basically I will be checking all the http requests made by the externally loaded swf and if it loads from one of my criteria then I have a separate function to call

Comment: that's what I want know. How can I accomplish this, I am not good with AS3, so I need a head start

Comment: updated anwser with a good link. I couldnt explain it better ;)